# How to make an instance globally acessible in C#?

Tags: c#, class, oop, instance

So I have a class.

I then make an instance somewhere:

```
Class1 somesinstance = new Class1;
```

Now I want to access this instance anywhere, is that possible?

Comment: Either make the class `static` or follow the Singleton pattern.

Comment: It's possible using the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), but it's frowned upon because it's usually (not always) a sign of bad design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, the elusive singleton pattern.

If you have a little spare time, I would highly recommend Jon Skeet's article on the subject: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Here is a simple example:

```
public sealed class YourSingleton
{
    private static readonly YourSingleton instance = new YourSingleton();

    static YourSingleton() {}

    private YourSingleton() { }

    public static YourSingleton Instance
    {
        get { return instance ; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a single instance, use the singleton pattern:

```
public class Class1
{
    private Class1()
    {
        ...
    }


    private static readonly Class1 _instance = new Class1();

    public static Class1 Instance { get { return _instance; } }
}
```

And access the instance like this:

```
Class1.Instance
```

Otherwise, just expose it as a static property in a class.

Answer (score 0):

If your anywhere mean your solution - You can use a static class with a static property

```
public static class Shared
{
    private static Class1 _myclass;

    public static Class1 MyClass{
         get
         {
             return _myclass??(_myclass=new Class1());
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can the Singleton Pattern as follows:

```
public class MyClass
{
     private static MyClass myClass;

     public static MyClass MyClassInstance
     {
          get { return myClass ?? (myClass = new MyClass()); }
     }

     private MyClass()
     {
          //private constructor makes it where this class can only be created by itself
     }
}
```

The instance can then be accessed globally like

```
MyClass.MyClassInstance
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static class that contains shared instances accessible from every class in you application.

```
public static class SharedResources
{
    public static Class1 obj1 {get; set;}
    public static Class2 obj2 {get; set;}

    // ...
}
```